# I can't install matplotlib using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

I am totally new to the Python and I wanted to use a matplotlib for my school project. I tried to install it using pip (`pip install matplotlib`), but I got a really long and bad-looking error and I don't know what to do... I was trying to upgrade pip and setuptools, but i didn't help. I don't understand this issue, because I installed for example numpy without any problem. Can anybody help me?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\marci_000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ze8b_ec\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\marci_000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6ze8b_ec\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\marci_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ze8b_ec\matplotlib\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\marci_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ze8b_ec\matplotlib\
    Complete output (228 lines):
    ================================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.1.1]
          python: yes [3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC
                      v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]]
        platform: yes [win32]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
             agg: yes [installing]
           tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl/Tk]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
            dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable DF
    Could not locate executable efl
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py:418: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
    C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
    c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 163, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 26, in run
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 142, in run
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 150, in build_sources
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 267, in build_py_modules_sources
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 2270, in generate_config_py
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 70, in mkpath
        os.mkdir(head, mode)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 310, in wrap
        path = self._remap_input(name, path, *args, **kw)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 452, in _remap_input
        self._violation(operation, os.path.realpath(path), *args, **kw)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 407, in _violation
        raise SandboxViolation(operation, args, kw)
    setuptools.sandbox.SandboxViolation: SandboxViolation: mkdir('C:\\Users\\MARCI_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\easy_install-fqlea6jp\\numpy-1.17.3\\build', 511) {}

    The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
    that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

    This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
    support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
    script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
    maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.


    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 443, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: SandboxViolation: mkdir('C:\\Users\\MARCI_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\easy_install-fqlea6jp\\numpy-1.17.3\\build', 511) {}

    The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
    that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

    This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
    support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
    script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
    maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.


    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 443, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
      File "C:\Users\MARCI_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-fqlea6jp\numpy-1.17.3\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: SandboxViolation: mkdir('C:\\Users\\MARCI_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\easy_install-fqlea6jp\\numpy-1.17.3\\build', 511) {}

    The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
    that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

    This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
    support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
    script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
    maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.


    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\marci_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6ze8b_ec\matplotlib\setup.py", line 262, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 717, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 787, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: SandboxViolation: mkdir('C:\\Users\\MARCI_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\easy_install-fqlea6jp\\numpy-1.17.3\\build', 511) {}

    The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
    that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

    This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
    support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
    script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
    maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: try ```python -m pip install matplotlib```

Comment: I've edited the comment. Try with ```python``` instead ```python3```

Comment: @PavelAntspovich I got the same error as before ;/

Comment: This is strange. I could recommend you to reinstall Python and install it with activated checkbox ```Add Python 3.8 to PATH```

Comment: I did it at least three times hahah! Also used a command prompt as an administrator, but nothing changed.

Comment: Do you use Win32?

Comment: I use Win64. And I have installed Python 3.8 64bit version

Comment: Me too. But I was trying to install this lib and I've installed it

Comment: Python 3.8 is very new - maybe it doesn't have matplotlib specially for 3.8.  Better uses Python 3.7 and wait few month till 3.8 will be better testes and modules will be created specially for 3.8

Comment: Interesting, I did the same thing on another PC and got exactly the same error. It seems, that it's my fault and I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what

Comment: @furas Ok, I will try with python 3.7 and we will see!

Comment: @furas It works with 3.7!! Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

Add your python to path and try running command in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

try to run
python -m pip install -U pip

python -m pip install -U matplotlib

while installing Matplotlib !